# How to ignore beginning of line in errorformat

Tags: quickfix, errorformat

I have error or warning messages from some tool with the following format:

```
2022-08-18T21:25:01.972 WARNING ##]  file:///Users/myuser/somedir/file.txt:123: Error: something went wrong
```

One of the built-in error formats erroneously matched the leading timestamp and `file://` as part of the file name. I need a format that ignores all of the stuff in the beginning but can’t come up with one. I don’t quite understand the advanced options from `:h errorformat`.
The version I have is this but it of course includes the beginning of the line in the file name as well: `%f:%l:\ %t%*\\a:\ %m`.

How can I fix my errorformat so that only the actual file name is matched?

i.e. this:   `/Users/myuser/somedir/file.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions as part of your errorformat definition.

See section [Pattern matching](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#efm-ignore) under `:help errorformat` for more details on the exact syntax to use in errorformat specification, for example you want `%.%#` for the equivalent of the `.*` regular expression.

In your case, you can use:

```
%.%#]%\\s%#file://%f:%l:\ %t%*\\a:\ %m
```

This will skip everything up to `]\s*file://` (where the `\s*` part matches optional whitespace) and start matching the `%f` at that point.

(You can also try to incorporate the `%t` matcher in your expression, to capture the error type, which is WARNING in your example.)