# How do I make a word optional in an errorformat?

Tags: errorformat

What's the syntax for optional tokens in an 'errorformat'?

### Details

Using Visual Studio, I have a `compiler/msvc.vim` setup like this:

```
CompilerSet errorformat&
CompilerSet errorformat^=%f(%l):\ %trror\ C%n:\ %m
```

It successfully captures errors like this (including capturing the error number):

```
c:\proj\stuff.cpp(71): error C2660: 'Stuff::Tick': function does not take 1 arguments
```

However, when I build a project with parallel project compilation enabled, I get output prefixed with a number and `>` (to identify each project's output):

```
1>c:\proj\stuff.cpp(71): error C2660: 'Stuff::Tick': function does not take 1 arguments
2>c:\proj\heavy\grill.cpp(71): error C2660: 'Grill::Tick': function does not take 1 arguments
```

I can change my errorformat to match the `1>`:

```
CompilerSet errorformat^=%*\\d>%f(%l):\ %trror\ C%n:\ %m
```

How do I modify my errorformat to **merge these two lines**? How do I do the equivalent of a capture `^\(\d>\)\?`

`:help efm-ignore` mentions:

> Important note: The (...) grouping of sub-matches can not be used in format specifications because it is reserved for internal conversions.

Does that mean the only way is to include lines with and without the `1>` matching pattern (all above lines) in my compiler script?

*[How to ignore beginning of line in errorformat](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/how-to-ignore-beginning-of-line-in-errorformat) doesn't answer my question because it's for discarding preamble that's always there.*

Comment: I found that the build *log file* doesn't include the `1>` characters. `:cgetfile c:\proj\obj\x64\debug\proj\proj.log` is a better solution than pasting from Visual Studio's Output Window for my example problem, but I'd still like to know if there's an answer.

Comment: The syntax for optional items would just be `%\\?`, I think, but the lack of grouping is a problem. Fortunately, there's really nothing wrong with multiple entries… You could also `:help errorformat` and `/^Filtering messages`: set `makeprg` to filter the numbers out?